# Reading 1 GB file in 10 KB chunks and saving in different location

Tags: node.js, stream

I want to read a 1 GB file in 10 KB chunk and move it to a different location (let say different folder for now) in Nodejs. I have read about various options in nodejs such as createReadStream, readFile. But Issue is, in my code I want to read file in 10 KB chunk only and pipe data somehow and save data.

Comment: Can I ask why `10KB` are important here?

Answer (score 1):

`ReadStream` and `readFile` read the file in chunks, but the size is not configurable. If this is critical for you, you will need to use the low-level file API methods like `fs.open`, `fs.read`, `fs.write`, and `fs.close`.